# How to move the foreign key column to another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

Let's say I have two tables like this

```
user_id     column1     column2    product_fk
___         ________    _______    ________
 1            text        text      1
 2            text        text      2
 3            text        text      3
```

and then

```
product_id     column1     column2    new_user_fk
___            ________    _______    ________
 1             text        text      
 2             text        text      
 3             text        text
```

I want to write a sql script that flips the fk relationship and have product reference user instead. How can I do that?

I'm using Postgres SQL 11

Comment: I would think you could add the fk contstraint to the product table and populate it via a join on user table, then drop the fk constraint and fk column of the user table.

Comment: Edited the question to include that thanks

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the edit.